# MPI_ALLreduce with Fortran and 2 bytes integer

Tags: memory-management, fortran, mpi

I'm trying to do an MPI sum of 2 bytes integer:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SIK2 = SELECTED_INT_KIND(2) 
INTEGER(SIK2) :: s_save(dim)
```

Indeed its an array which takes integer values from 1 to 48 max, so 2 bytes is enough for memory reasons.

Therefore I tried the following:

```
CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_F90_INTEGER(SIK2, int2type, ierr)
CALL MPI_ALLreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, s_save, nkpt_in, int2type, MPI_SUM, world_comm, ierr)
```

This works well for Gfortran + openmpi.

However in the case of intel I get a crash:

```
MPI_Allreduce(1000)......:   MPI_Allreduce(sbuf=MPI_IN_PLACE, rbuf=0x55d2160, count=987, dtype=USER<f90_integer>, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_SUM_check_dtype(106): MPI_Op MPI_SUM operation not defined for this datatype
```

Is there a proper (or recommended) way to do this so that it works for most compilers?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a library issue (e.g. Intel MPI vs Open  MPI) and not a compiler one (e.g. ifort vs gfortran). You can give a try to `MPI_INTEGER2` and if you are still stuck, you should report this to Intel directly.

Comment: First of all, `selected_int_kind(2)` is very likely to return a one-byte type. The parameter is not the number of bytes, but the precision in decimal digits, so you are asking for a type that can represent numbers from -100 to +100.

Comment: Second, you should pass the same value `2` to `MPI_Type_create_f90_integer` as the first parameter. You should not pass `SIK2`.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those solutions works: (i) the `MPI_INTEGER2` is not a supported type (does not even compile), this is why I had to create the type myself; (ii) Good to know, the precision in decimal digit going from -100 to +100 is fine for me; (iii) I tried passing 2 in `CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_F90_INTEGER(2, int2type, ierr)`, it does not change anything :(

Comment: which version of IntelMPI are you using? with `2018.3.222` and `2019.4.243` it compiles and works. I declared the buffer as `INTEGER*2` and used `MPI_INTEGER2`. If the problem persists, please edit your question and add a [MCVE]

Comment: Thanks Gilles. Indeed it works for me as well with intel 2019.